# common lisp: got different result with SBCL after saving image

Tags: common-lisp, package

(It's the first time for me to post a question here, I searched but didn't found any useful information....)

I found an *interesting* (which confused me for a whole damn morning) thing in common lisp.

I'm using SBCL 1.1.18 running on Gentoo/Linux. Here's my problem:

Suppose there's a package named eql-test which have an asd file, a package.lisp and a main.lisp (quite common config). Inside main.lisp, there's only one single function:

```
    (defun main ()
      (format t "~a~%" (eql 'hello (read-from-string "hello"))))
```

Now, if we run:

```
    sbcl --eval "(progn (load \"main.lisp\") \
      (sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die \"eql-test\" :toplevel #'main \
      :executable t))"
```

and then run the "eql-test" binary, we'll get an beautiful T.

However, if we use another file named "make.lisp" which contains:

```
    (asdf:load-system 'eql-test)
    (sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die "eql-test2"
          :toplevel #'eql-test:main
          :executable t)
```

and then run:

```
    sbcl --load "make.lisp"
```

then run the binary "eql-test2", it will give an NIL.

I don't understand why the same code gives different result (definitely the second one is not correct). Because it's a implicit bug of ASDF? Or there's anything wrong with my code?

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Could it be that the `'hello` in `eql-test` is in some `:eql-test` namespace, but `read-from-string` qualifies names with some toplevel namespace?

Comment: @Cactus Thanks for your comment. Wait....HaHa! That's it! It's just what you mentioned - I moved all everything to cl-user, it worked! It should because the two symbols are not in the same namespace...But I still don't understand why the output is different between direct "load" and "load-system"? They should be the same, because ASDF shouldn't affect the package namespace...

Comment: Well, I think I know the reason....(read-from-string) will intern the symbol into cl-user package, while a literal symbol would be interned in the package which the code is in....

Comment: Yes, that's roughly what I meant. When you `(load "main.lisp")` I assume none of the package wizardy happens, so it's equivalent to just copy-pasting the contents of `main.lisp`, and hence the original occurance of `'hello` (inside the definition of `main`) is interned into `cl:user`.

Comment: Maybe I should post it as a proper answer... but I don't know enough about SBCL's and ASDF's internals to be sure. My Lisp days are way behind me:)

Comment: @Cactus No problem...anyway, thanks a million for your help! :D

Comment: I guess that you are missing an `in-package` form in `main.lisp`.  It would help if you could post the entire files of your example.  Also, don't confuse systems and packages, see http://weitz.de/packages.html.

Comment: @Svante It's a very helpful website, and a good place to find libraries....Anyway, _Practical Common Lisp_ also has a good explanation on packages...Ses [this link](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic rule: **When in doubt, always control which package is used in source code, in IO operations, when creating new symbols, when searching for symbols, ...**

If you read from a string, you should make sure that any symbol created will be in the correct package. You can bind `*package*`:

```
CL-USER 1 > *package*
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 155/256 internal, 0/4 external>

CL-USER 2 > (read-from-string "FOO")
FOO
3
```

Above: `FOO` is in the `CL-USER` package.

Let's create a new package:

```
CL-USER 3 > (defpackage "BAR" (:use "CL"))
#<The BAR package, 0/16 internal, 0/16 external>
```

Global `*package*` has not changed:

```
CL-USER 4 > *package*
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 155/256 internal, 0/4 external>
```

Bind the variable:

```
CL-USER 5 > (let ((*package* (find-package "BAR")))
              (read-from-string "FOO"))
BAR::FOO
3
```

Above: `FOO` is in the package `BAR`.

Also make sure that any source code is a a defined package... make sure that the package is **not** changed by different ways to load the code...

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my point is, if you run the program in slime, the (read-from-string "foo") will return a symbol which is in TEST-EQL package. However, when you (save-lisp-and-die...) the file into an executable image and run it again, the (read-from-string) symbol will be in CL-USER package. (Note that the (read-from-string) are in TEST-EQL package.) That's strange :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer which seems to be correct....post here in order that might help.

Suppose you want `(eq 'foo (read-from-string "foo"))` to return T, which 'foo is in `MY-PACKAGE`.

First, and most IMPORTANT, if we do `(read-from-string "foo")` or `(intern "foo")` or `(find-symbol "foo")` or whatever, the real symbol read by the reader is `|foo|`, meaning that "foo" in lower case as the symbol name, but not `FOO` that we want. Because these function will exactly read the symbol you give as a string. So, `(read-from-string "FOO")` will return a symbol `FOO`. - That's exactly what we want.

Second, and also important, when we `(save-lisp-and-die ...)` in SBCL, (or use "buildapp" instead), and run the generated executable image file, we are in `COMMON-LISP-USER` package, but not anything else. So, actually LISP is trying to `eq` `MY-PACKAGE::FOO` and `COMMON-LISP::FOO`, which would be NIL.

FIX:
`(intern "FOO" :my-package)` should do the trick.

Attention:
`"name"` argument in `"intern"` function will be the SAME as symbol name, including case.